# Using css universal selector (*) for clearing the flow

Tags: css, css-float

This works, but actually I've never come across it earlier. Does it have some "weak spots"?

```
div.floated { float: left; }
div.floated+* { clear: both; }
```

Though I did not notice any "side effect".

Comment: Sometimes you may not want to clear the float. In other words, you may want to have two or more div.floated elements, so this will act as an issue.

Comment: Well, you don't want to clear the the float until just before the parent is closed. If you put a `<br>` before the end of parent then clear floats on the presence of that `div.floated > br {clear: both;}`, it'd work as you like.

Comment: What does the `+` achieve here, is it equivalent to a space?

Comment: `+` is the adjacent sibling selector. Here means that any element _next_ to floated `div` will have `clear:both;`. So - right, in case of single "floater" - there's no need to apply that rule to such sibling, whatever it can be (especially when content is dynamically generated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it at your will, although according to MDN, you should take into account that universal selector is the most expensive CSS selector in terms of webpage performance.

[Universal CSS Selector Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

Comment: It has support issues too from what i remember, then again, what doesn't. Curse you IE!

Comment: Considering the link above, and the idea to avoid the "clear-both'ing" `:after` pseudo-element in old browsers - due to their disastrous performance with `*` - I assume this case is worthless. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Here some problems I see:

1. "floated" is not a semantic class name.
2. This will clear adjacent elements after divs with the "floated" class, but not anything that is floated by other means.
3. In most designs I work with, I don't want to clear adjacent elements. Now I'll have to write more CSS to undo this.

I think I don't understand the value of this.